# Hide Download link from account Page in wooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I sell Digital Products thru my website. I use the "Free Downloads WooCommerce" Plugin to show the Download option on the product page. Now I want to Hide/disable the Default download link, that appears at the "My-account>Downloads" and "My-account>Orders" tab. is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by two ways using `woocommerce_account_downloads_columns` filter hook or using CSS. check the below code. code goes in your active theme functions.php file.

PHP

```
function remove_woocommerce_account_downloads_columns( $columns ){
    unset( $columns['download-file'] );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 'remove_woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 10, 1 );
```

CSS

```
function hide_woocommerce_account_downloads_columns(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .download-file{display:none !important;}
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_woocommerce_account_downloads_columns', 10, 1 );
```